# Java - Erasing with Line2D

Tags: java, graphics

I have created a simple paint program in java. I have run into a problem with the erasing tool. I can not allow the user to just paint with white paint to erase, because I want the background to be a picture. Anyway, I am trying to go about this by whenever the user draws with paint, trying to make it add a Line2D to an Array List. Then, I want the user to draw a white line on the program to show what is being erased. When the white line comes into a graphic, I want to get a result. Here's my code:

```
 al = new ArrayList<Line2D>();


    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

            if(graphics2D != null && paint.erase==false)
            {
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);


            repaint();
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;



        Line2D test=new Line2D.Float(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);

        al.add(test);
            //New system

        }
            if (paint.erase==true)
            {
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));
                graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);

                repaint();



                for( Line2D name : PadDraw.al ) {
                    boolean result = Line2D.linesIntersect(oldX,oldY,currentX,currentY,name.getX1(),name.getY1(),name.getX2(),name.getY2());
                    if (result==true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("paint found");
                    }
                    }


                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }

        }
        });
```

Comment: What are you painting to? Where does graphics2D come from?

Comment: I didn't think it was important but it is a Buffered Image and graphics2D= the Buffered Image.createGraphics();

Comment: It was because I thought you were breaking the paint chain ;)

Comment: You could use a special `Line2D` which represents the "erase line" which you could paint over the top of your `BufferedImage` when you paint it to the UI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really flexible solution that might work:

1. Create a `graphics` that is completely transparent and the same size as the picture
2. Draw black lines on it for erasures
3. Loop through the graphics. For every black pixel, copy the pixel from the image onto the `graphics` in the same place.
4. Render that graphics onto the original graphics

You will also be able to draw erasure rectangles, circles, etc. with this. However, you should not use it every time the mouse moves because it would take too long. You could temporarily draw some color in those spots to make up for this.

Comment: I like this answer! Is there any particular reason my code won't work? Am I missing something?

Comment: @ZacheryUtt Have you tried this way yet? I'm confused about which code won't work

Comment: @ZacheryUtt I haven't run your code yet but it looks like you are painting a color instead of the background over the graphics.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never thought of this! Thanks Again!